# Assessing deviations between actual and expected mortality rates with GAM models and confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, mortality, actuarial-science

I'm currently using a Generalized Additive Model (GAM) aimed at modelling mortality as a binary response (1 if the person has died and 0 otherwise). My primary goal is to compare the actual mortality rate with the expected mortality rate derived from this model to identify potential deviations in actual and expected experience over time.

To clarify, the actual mortality rate is determined by the number of deaths divided by the exposure, while the expected mortality rate is obtained by summing the probabilities generated by the GAM model and dividing by the exposure. Moreover, I'm considering fitting a GAM model based on data in some interval (e.g. deaths from Jan 2021-Jan 2024), and then using that model to derive predictions for months after Jan 2024 which I can compare with actual experience during the same time period.

In order to assess the significance of any deviations between the actual and expected mortality rates, I plan to construct confidence intervals around the actual mortality rate using the binomial proportions method and the Wald confidence interval formula:

$$\text{95% CI} = \text{mortality rate} \pm 1.96 \times \sqrt{\frac{\text{mortality rate} \times (1 - \text{mortality rate})}{\text{exposure}}}$$

My question is whether it's appropriate to compare the expected mortality rate predicted by the GAM model to the confidence interval to identify statistically significant deviations between the actual and expected rates. Additionally, I'm interested in understanding any issues or considerations with this approach.